# Slowing down and stopping a movie clip in flash AS3?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I need to slow down, then stop a movie clip animation usig AS3.
The slowdown will be triggered by clicking a stop button.

Anyone know a good technique for this? I can't use tweening engines for this effect as it's a school project which denies that type of libraries.

Comment: Timeline tweening allows you to set the amount of easing.

Comment: You couldn't just use ActionScript's own Tween class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can decrease framerate:

```
stage.frameRate = N;
```

But take into consideration, that this will decrease framerate of whole your SWF.

Comment: Simple enough for me, used this approach

Answer (score 1):

You can control the MovieClip instead of letting it play freely.

Here's a class you can use

```
package  
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class MovieClipController 
    {
        private var _mc:MovieClip;
        private var _playing:Boolean;
        private var _speed:Number;
        private var _currentFrame:Number;

        public function MovieClipController( mc:MovieClip ) 
        {
            _mc = mc;
            _mc.stop();
            _currentFrame = _mc.currentFrame;
        }

        public function play( speed:Number = 1 ):void 
        {
            if(!_playing) _mc.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, handleEnterFrame );
            _playing = true;            
            _speed = speed;
        }

        public function stop():void 
        {
            if(_playing) _mc.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, handleEnterFrame );
            _playing = false;           
            _mc.stop();
        }

        public function get speed():Number 
        {
            return _speed;
        }

        private function handleEnterFrame(e:Event):void 
        {
            if (_playing)
            {
                _currentFrame += _speed;
                _mc.gotoAndStop( Math.round(_currentFrame % _mc.totalFrames) );             
            }
        }


    }

}
```

Usage (assuming myAnimation is already added to the stage):

```
var myController:MovieCLipController = new MovieClipController( myAnimation );

...

myController.play(1.00); // plays animation at 100% speed

...

myController.play(0.50); // plays animation at  50% speed

...

myController.play(0.10); // plays animation at  10% speed, etc

...

myController.play( myController.speed * 0.90 ); // decrease speed by 10 percent.

...

myController.play( myController.speed - 0.10); // decrease speed by 10 percentage points
```

Comment: Didn't work for me, `myController.play(1.00)` just displayed the first frame and did not play at all.

Comment: I have updated the code. It works for me now. Please note that I removed the last trhee arguments in this line.

Please replace:
if(!_playing) _mc.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, handleEnterFrame, false, 0, true );

with:
if(!_playing) _mc.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, handleEnterFrame);

Comment: I now also edited a line to support looping MovieClips.

change this line:
_mc.gotoAndStop( Math.round(_currentFrame) );

with:
_mc.gotoAndStop( Math.round(_currentFrame % _mc.totalFrames) );

Answer (score 0):

Easiest and most logical way to approach this is to have a `velocity` property which you can decrease. Here is a class that could contain such a property:

```
package
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class PhysicsMovieClip extends MovieClip
    {
        // Properties
        private var _velocity:Number = 0;
        private var _angle:Number = 0;
        public var velocityTarget:Number = 0;


        /**
         * Constructor
         */
        public function PhysicsMovieClip()
        {
            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, _handle);
        }


        /**
         * ...
         * @param e Event.ENTER_FRAME
         */
        private function _handle(e:Event):void
        {
            _velocity -= (_velocity - velocityTarget) / 10;

            x += Math.cos(_angle) * _velocity;
            y += Math.sin(_angle) * _velocity;
        }


        /**
         * Getters & Setters
         */
        public function get angle():Number{ return _angle * 180 / Math.PI; }
        public function set angle(value:Number):void
        {
            _angle = value / 180 * Math.PI;
        }
    }
}
```

The above will let you alter the `velocityTarget` property which will slow down or speed up your object.

Example:

```
var mc:PhysicsMovieClip = new PhysicsMovieClip(); // assign graphics somewhere
addChild(mc);


mc.velocityTarget = 10; // the MovieClip will speed up
```

You'll be able to alter the direction of movement by setting the `angle` property above like so:

```
mc.angle = 90; // movement is now directly south
mc.angle = 270 // movement is now directly north
```

(0 degrees is directly east in flash)